# Reshape summarized data into vertical and tidy one in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have copied a summarized data from excel file then `dput` it as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(date = c(NA, NA, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L), area = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1573.98", "1574.95", "1580.86", 
"bj", "unit:m2"), class = "factor"), X = structure(c(4L, 5L, 
3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1831.15", "1871.61", "1927.95", "sh", 
"unit:m2"), class = "factor"), X.1 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("519.82", "529.47", "532.24", "tj", "unit:m2"
), class = "factor"), price = structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("20.67", 
"4.69", "7.49", "bj", "unit:dollar"), class = "factor"), X.2 = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("19.34", "21.99", "34.6", "sh", "unit:dollar"
), class = "factor"), X.3 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0.65", 
"2.76", "2.96", "tj", "unit:dollar"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

How could I reshape it from a summarized to a tidy vertical data as follows:

```
structure(list(city = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("bj", 
"sh", "tj"), class = "factor"), date = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("area", "price"), class = "factor"), values = c(1580.86, 
1927.95, 532.24, 1573.98, 1871.61, 529.47, 1574.95, 1831.15, 
519.82, 20.67, 34.6, 2.96, 7.49, 21.99, 2.76, 4.69, 19.34, 0.65
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
structure(list(city = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("bj", 
"sh", "tj"), class = "factor"), date = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("area", "price"), class = "factor"), values = c(1580.86, 
1927.95, 532.24, 1573.98, 1871.61, 529.47, 1574.95, 1831.15, 
519.82, 20.67, 34.6, 2.96, 7.49, 21.99, 2.76, 4.69, 19.34, 0.65
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df[-c(1:2), ] ## remove the two rows of headers

## create unique column names with consistent separator
names(df) <- c("date", "bj_area", "sh_area", "tj_area", "bj_price", "sh_price", "tj_price")  

## gather the areas variable and separate them by the separator to city and type
d1 <- df %>% gather(type, values, bj_area:tj_area) %>% separate(type, c("city", "type"), sep="_") %>% select(city, date, type, values)

## gather the price variable and separate them by the separator to city and type
d2 <- df %>% gather(type, values, bj_price:tj_price) %>% separate(type, c("city", "type"), sep="_") %>% select(city, date, type, values)

# rowbind the two datasets
do.call(rbind, list(d1, d2))

  city date  type  values
1    bj 2018  area 1580.86
2    bj 2019  area 1573.98
3    bj 2020  area 1574.95
4    sh 2018  area 1927.95
5    sh 2019  area 1871.61
6    sh 2020  area 1831.15
7    tj 2018  area  532.24
8    tj 2019  area  529.47
9    tj 2020  area  519.82
10   bj 2018 price   20.67
11   bj 2019 price    7.49
12   bj 2020 price    4.69
13   sh 2018 price    34.6
14   sh 2019 price   21.99
15   sh 2020 price   19.34
16   tj 2018 price    2.96
17   tj 2019 price    2.76
18   tj 2020 price    0.65
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `pivot_longer()` rather than `gather()` since it's [retired](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html)?